# Modify the "cat" command to automatically number paragraphs. These are separated by a single blank line

Tags: linux

What is the command to:
Modify the "cat" command to automatically number paragraphs. These are separated by a single blank line.

Comment: Maybe something like passing `cat -n` to `sed` or something along those lines?

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation? Try `man cat` in a terminal and see if that gets you somewhere to start with.

Comment: We have been confused. The link of Kusalananda does cover your question or you need something different?

Comment: I don't think he really means modifying the `cat` command itself, but process the output of it.

Comment: This is the link i'm talking about . This question seems a duplicate. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265779/how-to-number-paragraphs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually modify the `cat` command, the source can be found [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/cat.c;h=c7bb7e132c36c0fc800973a0eb00ceea12bcb8a6;hb=master); feel free to check it out and do whatever you like with it for your local compilation.  However, such a patch is unlikely to make it into any distribution of coreutils.

Comment: Thanks but I am not trying to do that. I just want to use something like "cat -n" but not sure what the command is to just number paragraphs instead of every line.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the man page, you will see that you can number non-blank **lines**, but I don't see any options for paragraphs.  You will probably need a `perl` script that increments a variable every time the input line is `^$`.

Comment: Perl script here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265779/how-to-number-paragraphs